# SqlAlchemy 2.x with specific columns makes scalars() return non-orm objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This question is probably me not understanding architecture of (new) sqlalchemy, typically I use code like this:

```
query = select(models.Organization).where(
    models.Organization.organization_id == organization_id
)
result = await self.session.execute(query)

return result.scalars().all()
```

Works fine, I get a list of models (if any).

With a query with specific columns only:

```
query = (
    select(
        models.Payment.organization_id,
        models.Payment.id,
        models.Payment.payment_type,
    )
    .where(
        models.Payment.is_cleared.is_(True),
    )
    .limit(10)
)

result = await self.session.execute(query)

return result.scalars().all()
```

I am getting first row, first column only. Same it seems to:   https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=scalar#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalar

My understanding so far was that in new sqlalchemy we should always call `scalars()` on the query, as described here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-orm-usage

But with specific columns, it seems we cannot use scalars() at all. What is even more confusing is that `result.scalars()` returns `sqlalchemy.engine.result.ScalarResult` that has fetchmany(), fechall() among other methods that I am unable to iterate in any meaningful way.

My question is, what do I not understand?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> My understanding so far was that in new sqlalchemy we should always call scalars() on the query

That is mostly true, but only for queries that return whole ORM objects. Just a regular `.execute()`

```py
    query = select(Payment)

    results = sess.execute(query).all()
    print(results)  # [(Payment(id=1),), (Payment(id=2),)]
    print(type(results[0]))  # <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>
```

returns a list of `Row` objects, each containing a single ORM object. Users found that awkward since they needed to unpack the ORM object from the `Row` object. So `.scalars()` is now recommended

```py
    results = sess.scalars(query).all()
    print(results)  # [Payment(id=1), Payment(id=2)]
    print(type(results[0]))  # <class '__main__.Payment'>
```

However, for queries that return individual attributes (columns) we don't want to use `.scalars()` because that will just give us one column from each row, normally the first column

```py
    query = select(
        Payment.id,
        Payment.organization_id,
        Payment.payment_type,
    )

    results = sess.scalars(query).all()
    print(results)  # [1, 2]
```

Instead, we want to use a regular `.execute()` so we can see all the columns

```py
    results = sess.execute(query).all()
    print(results)  # [(1, 123, None), (2, 234, None)]
```

Notes:

- `.scalars()` is doing the same thing in both cases: return a list containing a single (scalar) value from each row (default is index=0).
- `sess.scalars()` is the preferred construct. It is simply shorthand for `sess.execute().scalars()`.

Comment: @Gord Thompson It's my impression though that when they are loaded as rows rather than scalars, it's impossible to update the object because it's not bound to the session. Am I wrong?

Comment: Seems like you can't call convenient functions like `first()` or `one()` on `sess.scalars()`. However `sess.execute().scalars().first()` works. It really feels like the change from `query` to `select` adds a lot of boilerplate code down the line

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich re: "… it's not bound to the session. Am I wrong?" - Yes. Example [here](https://pastebin.com/g5Uk2Hb3).

Comment: @emilaz - No, `sess.scalars(query).one()` works just fine.

Comment: @GordThompson in your example, any mutation that you enact on row, would not be saved to the db

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich - Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean, but [this code](https://pastebin.com/BSGLJCGf) works correctly.

Comment: line 32 works for me with scalers_one() but not with one(). With one() the change is discarded and not saved to the db.

Comment: That's odd, with `.one()` it works fine for me using SQLAlchemy 2.0.9 and Python 3.11

Comment: for `sess.execute(query).all()` it returns `'coroutine' object has no attribute 'all'`. If I await the execution and print all results:
```
result = await session.execute(q)
print(result.all())
```

returns only the ids

Comment: it only works with `sess.execute(query).fetchall()`

Comment: @JoostDöbken - For async, you can either do `result = await session.execute(query)` followed by `rows = result.all()`, or you can do it on one line with `rows = (await session.execute(query)).all()`